# google play services libraries - android dev : reducing the library size?

Tags: android, google-play, size, libraries

I'm developing an android app with the google games services. I've already integrate the games services API to my app, and it's working fine.

My issue is that the full library of google games services gives a huge size (more than 5 Mo) to the installed app on my terminal, and it's very inconvenient...

I'm developing for android 2.3 with android 4.4.2 platform with the Support libraries v4 and google play services libraries. In the code, I'm only using games achievements part of google play services. I've created a BaseGameActivity which access to all functions I need to unlock reveal or display achievements. I had many problems to integrate BaseGameActivity to my project as a library so I include the 4 .class files "BaseGameActivity", "BaseGameUtils", "GameHelper" and GameHelperUtils". I know it isn't the good way but it works.

I would reduce the size of the google play services libraries, deleting part that I'm not using in my app but I don't know what .class I'm using with the achievements.

Have you some idea ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might be of help to you if you're using gradle for building the app:
https://gist.github.com/dmarcato/d7c91b94214acd936e42

I am not sure which classes are unnecessary for achievements but you can start by stripping all and then you'll find out what is missing when trying to build since it will throw an exceptions for missing code.